# Bundle library to application using pybuilder

Tags: python, linux, pybuilder

I'm new to python and writing an application which I want to package for debian. Therefore, I'd like to (and I have to) use *pybuilder*. My goal is to create a .deb package (currently using *stdeb*), which makes sure, that all required libraries are installed, too.
My application uses a third party library, that is only available via *pip(3) install* (no debian package).

My `build.py` looks like:

```
[...]
use_plugin("python.core")
use_plugin("python.unittest")
use_plugin("python.install_dependencies")
use_plugin("python.distutils")
use_plugin("copy_resources")
use_plugin("source_distribution")
use_plugin("python.flake8")
use_plugin("python.coverage")
use_plugin("python.stdeb")

@init
def initialize(project):
    project.build_depends_on('coverage')
    project.build_depends_on('flake8')
    project.build_depends_on('jsonmerge')
    project.build_depends_on('mock')
    project.build_depends_on('setuptools')
    project.build_depends_on('stdeb')
    project.build_depends_on('unittest-xml-reporting')
    project.build_depends_on('xmlrunner')

    project.depends_on('<pip-only-library>')

    project.set_property('coverage_threshold_warn', 50)
    project.set_property('flake8_break_build', False)
    project.set_property('flake8_ignore', 'E501,E402,E731')
    project.set_property('flake8_include_test_sources', True)
    project.set_property('flake8_verbose_output', True)
    project.set_property('verbose', True)
    project.set_property("copy_resources_target", "$dir_dist")
    project.set_property("coverage_break_build", False)
    project.set_property("coverage_reset_modules", True)
    project.set_property("dir_dist_scripts", 'scripts')

    project.set_property("distutils_classifiers", [
                         'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
                         'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.3',
                         'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4',
                         'Development Status :: 4',
                         'Environment :: Console',
                         'Intended Audience :: Systems Administration',
                         'License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License'])

    project.set_property('distutils_commands', ['bdist'])
    project.set_property('distutils_commands', ['sdist'])
```

Generation of debian package works in general. Calling `pyb` successfully creates a `python3-mypackage_1.0-1_all.deb` package.
The generated *setup.py* looks like:

```
# `target/dist/mypackage-1.0/setup.py`
[...]
if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup(
        [...]
        packages = [],
        [...]
        entry_points = {},
        data_files = [],
        package_data = {},
        install_requires = ['pip-only-library'],
        dependency_links = [],
        zip_safe=True,
        cmdclass={'install': install},
    )
```

Testing package installation using `sudo dpkg -i python3-mypackage_1.0-1_all.deb` fails as *dpkg* refers to a dependent package `python3-<pip-only-library>`, which is not available.

During build time, the library is present on the local machine.
So, now comes the newbie question: How to change `build.py` to make sure, that the created debian package provides my application and makes sure, that library requirements are met.
Maybe, is it possible to bundle the pip-only library (i.e. taken from `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages` during build-time) to my application and ship them within an 'application with all dependencies'-package? Or is there an alternative approach?

I've already seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856528/include-a-library-in-python-application) but it doesn't help.